# How to add conditional operation in Mongodb's Aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have transaction documents like:

```
{code: 'BUY001', timestamp: ISODate("..."), type: 'buy', qty: 500},
{code: 'SELL001', timestamp: ISODate("..."), type: 'sell', qty: 10},
{code: 'SELL002', timestamp: ISODate("..."), type: 'sell', qty: 80},
{code: 'BUY002', timestamp: ISODate("..."), type: 'buy', qty: 50}
```

And I want to sum all sell/buy transactions listed here, sort by their timestamp to get  the end result of my item. Here's my traditional solution:

```
db.transaction.find().sort({timestamp: 1}, function(err, reply){
   var total = 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < reply.length; i++){
     if(reply[i].type === 'buy')       total += reply[i].qty;
     else if(reply[i].type === 'sell') total -= reply[i].qty;
   }
   return console.log(total); // TOTAL IS THE RESULT
})
```

Can I have aggregate equivalent of the function above ? Any suggestions? 
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using  [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) and [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)

```js
db.transaction.aggregate([
    /* Group all documents.
       Sum all type matching 'buy' and store in a field called buy. 
       Sum all type matching 'sell' and store in a field called sell. 
    */
    {$group:{
            '_id':null, 
            'buy':{$sum:{
                     $cond:[
                          {$eq:["$type", "buy"]}, 
                          "$qty", 
                          0 ]
                  }
            },
            'sell':{$sum:{
                     $cond:[ 
                        {$eq:["$type", "sell"]}, 
                          "$qty", 
                          0 ]
                  }
            }
        }
    }, 

    /* Subtract buy field with sell field. */
    {$project: {
            "total": {$subtract:["$buy", "$sell"]}
        }
    }
]);
```

Using the 4 documents that you have given, the result should be 460.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate with `$sum` operation to find total for each type.

```
output = db.test.aggregate([
    {
        '$group' : {
            '_id' : '$type',
            'total' : {$sum : '$qty'}
        }
    }
]).toArray()
```

And then you will get result as below.

```
[
    {
        "_id" : "sell",
        "total" : 90
    },
    {
        "_id" : "buy",
        "total" : 550
    }
]
```

Using these array you can find your desired output with

```
output[1].total - output[0].total
```